# Ignoring the connected WCF Service when registering a .Net Standard 2.0 DLL?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, wcf, dll, .net-standard-2.0

I currently have a .Net Standard DLL that I create through Visual Studio 2019. This library has a WCF service connected within it that contains a GetPassword and GetHealthCheck method in it. 
When I build the .Net Standard project in release mode (I have it set to build for both Standard and Framework 4.7.1) the DLL is created, but when I register it all that I can see in my registry is the WCF methods. My actual class methods aren't there, and they don't appear in the registry either.
[image: My Visual Studio Window]

[image: My registry window]

I would like to think that the registry values would be the CyberarkUserIDPasswordRetrieval class instead.
Is there another setting within visual studio that I should flip to have it ignore the connected service?

Comment: Should be noted that the class names/service name is arbitrary, I ran into the same issue renaming everything and using a different pre-existing service.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that your .cs files have been included in a manner which means they are not compiled. Files added to a solution have an action associated with them:

[image: Visual Studio build action]

(Example is for .vb or Visual Basic .net code files but the behaviour is the same)

It usually doesn't make sense for the build action of a .cs file to be anything other than `Compile`.

Comment: I checked the class specific files and they all have the "C# Compiler" build action. Should I possibly change the build action of the reference.cs file to not compile?